# how to show html on pop over using angular ui bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I make demo of pop over like this .It show a pop over on right side when I click the button .But now problem is that how I will show some html on pop over .

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button popover-placement="right" popover="On the Right!" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </body>
<script>
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

</script>  

</html>
```

I have this HTML I need to how on  add this on pop over .I know there is way in bootrap.js to add html on popover .I don't want to use that I want to use angular UI bootrap.js

```
<div ng-controller="axcont">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="add()">add row</li>
  <li class="list-group-item " ng-click="deleteRow($index)">Deleterow</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I did more try on that like that but getting undefined.May be I am wrong I just doing RND

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button pop-over title="Mode of transport" content-url="pop.html" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </body>
<script>
var a=angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
a.directive('popOver', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function popOverPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $http.get(attrs.contentUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).success(
        function (tmpl) {
          var options = {
            content: $compile(tmpl)(scope),
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: true,
            trigger:'click',
            title: attrs.title
          };
          elem.popover(options);
          scope.hidePopover = function () {
            elem.popover('hide');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
});

</script>  

</html>
```

Comment: In your code above, you are using the `bootstrap.js` with `elem.popover`.

Comment: yes..but I don't want to use bootstrap.js.I want to use only angular UI bootstrap to make pop over.some developer said it better to uses Angular UI botrap because it gives all callback event

Comment: @runTarm do you have any idea make pop over without bootrap.js

Comment: This is not support out of the box by Angular UI Bootstrap yet, see a long discussion [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/220). You have to create your own custom directive or consider using another project [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers)

Comment: @runTarm thanks for giving information can you using my html and load it on button click if you have idea of custom directive

Comment: I study you link it id too complicated to study http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview ..can you just make simple example to load my html on button click

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularUI Bootstrap directive tooltip-html-unsafe

```
<span tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>Hi</div><div>Hi Hi Hi</div><div>Hi</div>">   
   <b>Hover on Me!</b>
</span>
```

Demo and code is in here [Plnkr tooltip-html-unsafe](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cs5V7eT3sm90JZDgiv2U?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for giving answer .but there is issue in that ..I need that on click ..secondly why you are using this  $scope.htmlTooltip = '<div><span>Hi I am a tooltip</span></div>';

Comment: I forgot to remove the $scope.htmlTooltip = '<div><span>Hi I am a tooltip</span></div>'; I fixed in the plnkr.

Comment: Got your update. You want tooltip on click not on hover ? Is that correct ?

Comment: yes thank if you take my html it is more better (having ul and li)

Comment: why I am saying to take my html because  I need to take click event of li

Comment: Can you create a plnkr ?

Comment: give me second ….I will give you

Comment: I am not sure it is angular UI bootrap .But I need to use angular UI bootstrap without using bootrap.js file here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rmPtVeOIffQye30kLaJ6?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59001/discussion-between-user2535959-and-bhantol).

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs [Angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you should be defining the popover as `uib-popover` instead of just `popover`, and if you would like to bind html to the popover you would either use `uib-popover-html="<div> hello </div>"` or template binding `uib-popover-template="<<teamplateNameHere>>"`

Answer (score 0):

In your options, add a templateUrl.

For example:

```
templateUrl: 'your/url' + type + 'popup.html'
```

More info: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Answer (score 0):

**tooltip-html-unsafe** With Image and Style Tag

```
<span tooltip-html-unsafe="<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Lubuntu-icon.png' style='width:24px;'>
      <div style='font-size:24px;'>Tooltip With Image</div>">   
           <b>Hover on Me!</b>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**tooltip-html-unsafe**you can put anything in it

Comment: This does not add anything that the other existing answers do not already cover. It would be better to upvote or comment on the other answers if you do not have anything new to add.