# Drag and drop functionality not working angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I want integration of jquery UI and Angular js. I want to drag and drop the list row.

So I googled it found this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/) and have made same demo but when I use latest angular, it gives error, I also use latest Jquery UI.
I have created module with "ui", I am getting error still. So where I am doing wrong, I want to drag the row using only "+" button, in other words I don't want to drag and drop from whole row. I just wanted if I can drag and drop using "+", can we get event after drop?

plunker [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qeN5LmrXSrwA4IOXOK9R?p=preview)

```
app.controller('dragcontr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok there was some mistakes in your application:

1) You did not reference the angular-ui directive so the sortable wasn't even available.

```
<script data-require="angular-ui" data-semver="0.4.0" src="http://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

2) You did not initialize the ui as a directive on your app:

```
var app =angular.module('dragapp',['ngRoute', 'ui']);
```

3) You initialized the sortable on the wrong element. You attached the tag to the `table` element which makes the `tbody` elements sortable. Instead you should attach it to the `tbody` to make the `tr` tags sortable.

```
<tbody ui:sortable="sortableOptions">
```

4) I added some sortable options to your controller to make the glyphicon the drag handle and to show you the stop event after dropping.

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
      handle: '.glyphicon-plus',
      stop: function(){
         alert('stopped dragging');
      }
}
```

And a working plunkr of it all together:
[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5dVdDfCA2jkln5lT36qX?p=preview)

Comment: Please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215295/how-to-show-html-on-pop-over-using-angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: @user2535959 I am not sure what you mean by *I am looking for same*? It seems like somebody else answered your other question?

Comment: no sorry ..it mean you give correct answer..thanks a lot

Comment: if you know this anser please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-from-json-using-angular

Answer (score 0):

hello its ok in my example below

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CategoryManagement.aspx.cs" Inherits="HaselOne.CategoryManagement" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="startup_scripts" runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/Css/Misc/TreeViewFix.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="CategoryManagementController">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
                 <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="item.Categories && item.Categories.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span
                         class="fa"
                         ng-class="{
                                 'fa-chevron-right': collapsed,
                                 'fa-chevron-down': !collapsed
                                   }"></span></a>
                        {{item.CategoryName}}
                  </div>
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.Categories" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in item.Categories" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
                    </li>
                 </ol>
        </script>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group" style="left: 25px;">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="expandAll()">Expand all</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="collapseAll()">Collapse all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div ui-tree="treeOptions">
                    <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="list">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <label><b>Ana Kategori</b></label>
                    <input class="form-control hero" type="text" id="txtSelectedCategyName" ng-value="selectedCategoryName" ng-attr-title="{{selectedCategoryId}}" runat="server" placeholder="Seçilen Kategori" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <label><b>Yeni Eklenecek Kategori Adı</b></label>
                    <input class="form-control hero" type="text" id="txtCategoryName" ng-model="NewCategoryName" runat="server" placeholder="Kategori Yazınız" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Add()">Yeni Kategori Ekle</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="Delete()">Seçilen Kategoriyi Sil</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Reload()">Yenile</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptbase" runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/_Controllers/CategoryManagementController.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

and its angular controller

```
HaselApp.controller('CategoryManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', "$q", function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $q) {
    $scope.GetCategories = function (success, error) {
        $http.post('/CategoryManagement/GetCategoriesAll').then(
    function (response) {
        if (response.data.IsSuccess)
            $scope.list = response.data.Data;
    }
    , function error(e) { console.log("GetCategoriesAll error", e) });
    }
    $scope.GetCategories();
    $scope.toggle = function (scope) {
        scope.toggle();
    };
    $scope.collapseAll = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:collapse-all');
    };

    $scope.expandAll = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('angular-ui-tree:expand-all');
    };

    $scope.UpdateCategory = function (sourceId, destId) {
        $http.post('/CategoryManagement/SetCategoryByNodeId', { source: sourceId, dest: destId }).then(
        function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.collapseAll();
            }, 200);
        }
        , function error(e) { console.log("SetCategoryByNodeId error", e) });
        console.log("source/dest", sourceId, destId);
    }

    $scope.Add = function () {
        $http.post('/CategoryManagement/AddNewCategory', { newCategoryName: $scope.NewCategoryName, parentId: $scope.selectedCategoryId }).then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.GetCategories();
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.collapseAll();
            }, 200);
        }
        , function error(e) { console.log("AddNewCategory error", e) });
        console.log("catName/parentId", $scope.NewCategoryName, $scope.selectedCategoryId);
    }
    $scope.NewCategoryName = '';

    $scope.Delete = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $scope.AlertService.Confirm("\"" + $scope.selectedCategoryName + "\" kategorisini silmek istediğinizden eminmisiniz (!Dikkat bu değişiklik geri alınamaz)?", "", function (result) {
            if (result) {

                $http.post('/CategoryManagement/DeleteCategory', { desCategoryId: $scope.selectedCategoryId }).then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.GetCategories();
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.collapseAll();
                    }, 200);
                }
                , function error(e) { console.log("DeleteCategory error", e) });
                console.log("desCategoryId", $scope.selectedCategoryId);

            }
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    $scope.Reload = function ReloadCategories() {
        $scope.GetCategories();
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.collapseAll();
        }, 200);
    }

    $scope.treeOptions = {
        beforeDrop: function (e) {
            $scope.selectedCategoryName = e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue.CategoryName;
            $scope.selectedCategoryId = e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue.Id;
            var sourceId = 0;
            var destId = 0;
            if (typeof e.source !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof e.dest !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof e.source.nodeScope !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof e.dest.nodesScope !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof e.dest.nodesScope.item !== 'undefined') {
                sourceId = e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue.Id;
                destId = e.dest.nodesScope.item.Id;
            }
            if (sourceId != destId && typeof e.dest.nodesScope.item.Id != 'undefined' && e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue.ParentId != e.dest.nodesScope.item.Id) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $scope.AlertService.Confirm("Hiyerarşiyi değiştirmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", "", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $scope.UpdateCategory(sourceId, destId);
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.collapseAll();
    }, 200);
}]);
```